# Getting Window info from its HWND

Tags: c++, mfc, window, information-extraction

I have this code:

```
HWND WindowHandle;
WindowHandle = FindWindowA( WindowClass, WindowName );

if( WindowHandle != NULL)
{
     // here I want to populate a listbox with the window's information like
     // its process name and PID, executable file name,  and its window title.
}
```

I already know how to get the Window Title, with `SendMessage();` and `WM_GETTEXT`, but I want to know how to get it's process name and PID, and also the executable file location and name.

Could anyone help me?

Please note that I am working with C++ MFC.

Answer (score 0):

Windows offers a function called [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It sounds like what you want.

Disclaimer: I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PID in `PROCESS_INFORMATION`. Just declare say: `PROCESS_INFORMATION pi` and access PID like this: `pi.hProcesss` `pi.dwProcessId`.